# как поместить массив в конкретный div

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Есть массив со значениями необходимо значения поместить в блок на странице( допустим div class='menu') 
  Пытался сделать но как-то плохо вдупляю как это делать правильно

```
let dataObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
let menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
dataObject.forEach(function(item,i,arr){
     menu+='<li>'+item+'</li>';
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов несколько, вот 2 наиболее распространенных, но я бы еще взглянул на массив `xhr.responseText`, для полной уверенности.

```js
let dataObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
let menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
dataObject.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
  menu.innerHTML += '<li>' + item + '</li>';
});

// вариант побыстрее
let dataObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
let menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
dataObject.forEach(item => {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = item;
  menu.appendChild(li);
});
```

Comment: в 1ом случае не отображает ,во втором ошибка menu.appendChild is not a function  ,массив xhr.responseText ["explicit", "dev", ....]

Comment: @ЛёшаСугуров ой, опечаточка, конечно же `appendChild` (e и n местами перепутал).

Comment: Не используйте '.innerHTML +=' перепешите свой ответ с использованием https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML